# Using cursor.execute arguments in pymssql with IN sql statement

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I have troubles using a simple sql statement with the operator IN through pymssql.

Here is a sample :

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='myserver', database='mydb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
req = "SELECT * FROM t1 where id in (%s)"
cursor.execute(req,  tuple(range(1,10)))
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

Surprisingly only the first id is returned and I can't figure out why.
Does anyone encounter the same behavior ?

Comment: Have never used pymssql, but for SQLite, this would require use of `cursor.executemany()`

Comment: I tried it and it returns the data corresponding to the last element of my tuple.

Comment: as  i am not 100% sure, i will not yet post is as an answer. it looks like you are only passing `SELECT * FROM t1 where id in (1)`. You call `execute` with the tuple but the string only has one formatter, i know that this is the way for tuples but maybe pymsql interprets it differently

Comment: @Alex if cursor.executemany() returns the last element and cursor.execute() returns the first, this means it is querying one values at a time. You might try concatenating the tuple and passing it as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass nine ID values to the query and you only have one placeholder. You can get nine placeholders by doing this:

```
ids = range(1,10)
placeholders = ','.join('%s' for i in ids)
req = "SELECT * FROM t1 where id in ({})".format(placeholders)
cursor.execute(req, ids)
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

As an aside, you don't necessarily need a tuple here. A list will work fine.

Comment: Thank you, this works. My only concern would be if I had a lot of ids but I'm ok for now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only passing `SELECT * FROM t1 where id in (1)`. You call `execute` with the tuple but the string only has one formatter. To pass all values, call `execute` like this:

```
cursor.execute(req,  (tuple(range(1,10)),))
```

This will pass the tuple as first argument to the string to format.

EDIT: Regarding the `executeone/many()` thing, if you call `executemany` and it returns the last instead of the first id, it seems that `execute` will run the query 10 times as it can format the string with 10 values. The last run will then return the last id.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence, I tried it with the execute and it returns an error telling me that there is an incorrect syntax near ','. Full error : pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near ','.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: The syntax is correct however when I use executemany but it retrieves only the first element.